# JavaScript queue implementation using linked list

Tags: javascript, queue

Are there better ways of modularizing the code? Does it contain things JavaScript experts would avoid? Is it idiomatic? Is there a better way of signaling an empty queue than returning `null`?

```
function makeQueue () {
  // types
  let Node = {
    next : null,
    data : null  
  };

  // data
  let head = null;
  let size = 0;

  // methods
  function enqueue(x) {
    let newNode = {...Node, next : head, data : x};
    head = newNode;
    size++;
  }

  function dequeue() {
    if (size === 0) {
      return null;
    }

    let x = head.data;
    head = head.next;
    size--;

    return x;
  }

  function getSize() {
    return size;
  };

  // public
  return {
    enqueue : enqueue,
    dequeue : dequeue,
    getSize : getSize
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some observations in addition to the other answer:

- inconsistent space between function name and `()` - use eslint or similar to prevent typos
- `Node` is used as a template for extra properties, not as a type, so I doubt its name should be capitalized as though it's a class. Also, it's effectively unused in your code.
- `const` in JS is [not for named constants only](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653), but for any value that's assigned just once:

  > The reason is simple, it's much easier to reason about code when it is dead obvious what can change and what cannot change. [...]
  >
  > Going back and changing a const to a let is dead simple. And going const by default makes you think twice before doing so. And this is in many cases a good thing.
  >
  > How many bugs have you seen that involved variables changing unexpectedly? I'd guess a lot. I know that the majority of bugs that I see involve unexpected state changes. You won't get rid of all of these bugs by liberally using const, but you will get rid of a lot of them!

  + if you use a JavaScript IDE, it'll warn about accidental reassignment of a `const` identifier.
- A separate assignment statement with `newNode` doesn't seem warranted as the code would be just as obvious with a direct assignment to `head`.
- `getSize` is too verbose. I suggest exposing it as `size` just like the read-only `size` getter in Map and Set.
- Since you're using ES2015, also use object literal shorthand:

  ```
  return {
    enqueue,
    dequeue,
    size: getSize
  };
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I'll reply to your questions in a random order, hope it's okay.

> Is there a better way of signaling an empty queue than returning `null`?

Returning `null` is okay-ish for as long as the consuming will not need to store `null` as a valid value. IMO, there are two better ways. Which one to choose is up to you.

I am personally a big fan of *defensive programming* and *fail fast* approach. Thus, I'd prefer to `throw new Error('Queue is empty -- nothing to dequeue.')` so that the consuming code *breaks instead of hiding a bug*. I say "bug", because when a queue is empty, nobody should not even try to `dequeue()` from it.

If you disagree, you can at least make your class consistent with JavaScript. Return the same thing as the one returned by an empty array when `pop()` is called (which is `undefined`):

[image: pop on empty array]

---

> Is it idiomatic?

I think, it is. The only thing that confuses me is this:

```
let newNode = {...Node, next : head, data : x};
               ^^^^^^^
```

Not sure why this line can not be simplified to `let newNode = { next: head, data: x};` Similarly, I don't see much value in `Node` "type" if it's not really used as a type anywhere in the code.

---

> Are there better ways of modularizing the code?

It looks good to me.

---

> Does it contain things JavaScript experts would avoid?

I'm not an "expert", so leaving this part for someone else to answer.