# JavaScript Queue Attempt #2

Tags: javascript, stack, queue

This is a follow-up review to [JavaScript queue implementation using linked list](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178638/javascript-queue-implementation-using-linked-list)

I've run the code through a linter, fixed every style error, added `const` where it was possible, removed extraneous templates and changed the return policy for calling `dequeue()` on an empty queue to make it fail fast. I also implemented an `empty()` method for the user's convenience.

I'm still undecided as to whether to use single or double quotes for strings. The linter suggests single quotes, but I've read reviews suggesting double quotes might be better because they look less like backticks, which are used for template literals.

Is there anything I've missed?

```
function makeQueue() {
  // data
  let head = null;
  let size = 0;

  // methods
  function enqueue(x) {
    let newNode = {next: head, data: x};
    head = newNode;
    size++;
  }

  function dequeue() {
    if (size === 0) {
      throw new Error('dequeue() on an empty queue');
    }

    const x = head.data;
    head = head.next;
    size--;

    return x;
  }

  function getSize() {
    return size;
  };

  function isEmpty() {
    return size === 0;
  };

  // public
  return {
    enqueue,
    dequeue,
    size: getSize,
    empty: isEmpty
  };
}

var q0 = makeQueue();
var q1 = makeQueue();
var q2 = makeQueue();

for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  q0.enqueue(i);
}

console.log(q0.size());
console.log(q1.empty());
console.log(q2.size());
```

**Edit**

The goal here was to improve the JavaScript, I only realized now that I actually wrote a LIFO stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good!

I'm a bit surprised the linter didn't catch redundant semicolons at the end of some function declarations, for example here:

> ```
>   function getSize() {
>     return size;
>   };
> ```

I would rename all the local variables and function parameters named `x` to `data`.

In `enqueue`, you could inline the `newNode` variable,
and assign the object literal `{next: head, data: data}` directly to `head`.

It would be good to test a bit more thoroughly,
for example dequeue everything from a non-empty queue,
and performing a mix of enqueue and dequeue operations.